# Storing a group of ids in postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a master table of books with primary Key Ids (1,2,3) . I need to store a relationship which says Book 1 is similar book 2 , book 3 .

The need is that I should be able to find out the similar book by just joining the master table and this relationship table .What is the best way to store this?

There are two approaches .
First Approach :

```
1,2
1,3
2,3
2,1
3,1
3,2
```

Second is using a postgres array :

```
1 -> [2,3]
2 -> [3,1]
3 -> [1,2]
```

What are the pros and cons ? is there any other approach we are missing ?

Comment: `1NF, all data in columns should be atomic.` I would use first approach, but as always it depends.

Comment: Depends on what other things . I understand First approach is the way traditional DBA will do . But what are things we  might lose if we use arrays in this case ?

Comment: For example: you may need to use array operators/functions when update/search/delete. It could be slower than atomic indexed column. For joining with other columns you need to split it first etc. What with uniqueness of values in array like `[2,2,2]`?

Comment: okay , in this particular case , there will not be any atomic operations , After the initial insert , its is always going to read only data .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pros and cons.  Let's start with the fact that your first approach is 1NF and your second is not as I understand it (it could be, see below), and what the implications are. Basically you want to start with your first approach, but note that in some environments, you have to do something like the second.

First what we mean by atomic (mentioning because most people get it wrong):  a value is atomic if it refers to a single value in its domain.  That doesn't rule out arrays but one has to think about arrays as geared for atomic values (an SQL array is basically a math matrix, and they are ordinal).  As I have pointed out elsewhere, an array is atomic if ordinality matters.  top_five int[] is atomic, as is ip_address int[] (representing an IP address as an ordered array of int values).  This means you can do things with the group you cannot do with the individual elements.  In general two things break atomicity:  sets (which I think you are trying to do here if I am not mistaken, but sets are unordered while sql arrays are ordered, so if you are relying on ordering this doesn't apply), and cases where one array member is functionally dependent on another array member (not applicable here).

so what we are talking about here are the pros and cons of first normal form vs non-first normal form designs in PostgreSQL.  Moreover you have a definite case here so it is possible to talk about these not in the abstract but in the concrete.

Also unlike most people I have hands-on experience with both approaches.  My recommendation is go with your first approach if you can, but understand the second if you need it.

**Write Concurrency**

Your first approach will support much better write concurrency than your second one (and see more about indexing below).  If you want to delete one similarity while adding another similarity (both to the same book), transactions won't trip over eachother locking-wise in your first case but they will in your second case, because both are stored in the same row and require waiting for the row lock.

In other words, the first will scale much better for writes even before we start talking about index update performance (which would be real overhead).

**Data Integrity**

A second problem you have is data integrity.  It is possible to define unique constraints in your first case that cannot be expressed in your second reasonably well.  You can express them but they become a lot more work to maintain.  If you go this route, you need to think much more closely and you may need to write custom functions that check what you need to verify.  That is more work and it also adds to write performance (well above what the maintenance of a unique index would.

You would also have to write constraint triggers to address what happens if you delete a book. That is likely to be painful and another maintenance issue.  In the cases where projects I have been involved with have used this approach, we usually accept that some data will be inconsistent and build things to be tolerant towards missing links.  That is a very significant tradeoff but it is sometimes necessary.

**Indexing and Read Performance**

PostgreSQL has GIN indexes which allow for easy indexing of array membership.  GIN indexes for certain cases are the only reason you would choose the second, but they too are not without costs.  GIN indexes are update-costly but read-efficient.  So people often in PostgreSQL break automicity to do things like store arrays of tags.

If your data is seldom updated, you have major read performance issues, and have exhausted other possibilities, this approach makes sense especially if you can tolerate orphaned links here.

**Overall Recommendation**

Your first solution is much better for the general case.  There are cases where the second one works better but you need to be aware that a lot of problems pop up when you start doing that....